# Convert String to Extended ASCII Decimal

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, decimal, ascii

With my program a user can type a text in a JTextfield. The text will be saved in a string (in the code below "strLine1") and should be converted to decimal numbers.

Therefor i use getBytes.

```
bytearray1 = strLine1.getBytes();
```

This is my code for the output:

```
for (int i=0; i<bytearray1.length; i++) {
                    builder1.append(bytearray1[i]);
                    if(i != bytearray1.length) 
                        builder1.append("• ");
}
```

This works well but when i type in some special charakters like "ß" or "ö" i get outputs like "-33" or "-10". I read a lot about but didn't get ahead.

The result for "ß" has to be 225 and "ö" 148 like on this page:
http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png

The characters are listed there as "extended ASCII".

I also tried several charsets but didn't come to the right result.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Figure out [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings) encoding that is and then see if your Java [supports](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Java-charset-Supported-Character-Encodings-in-JDK.html) it.

Comment: It's Codepage 858 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_858)    (code points 0–127) are the same as ASCII. But i don't know exactly how to use that now with toCharArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i got a solution which worked well for me:

I changed it back to getBytes to the following:

```
try {                                                   
                bytearray1 = strLine1.getBytes("CP858");
    }           catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here i'm using the correct Codepage (858).

And here is my output:

```
for (int i=0; i<bytearray1.length; i++) {               
                    builder1.append((int)bytearray1[i] &0xff);      
                    if(i != bytearray1.length) 
                        builder1.append("• ");
                }
            }
```

So the "&0xff" converts it from signed to unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toCharArray()` instead of `getBytes()`.

I will leave the rest of the learning of why up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, byte can not save higher numbers than 127. Didn't mention that. So i changed it to:

```
chararray1 = strLine1.toCharArray();
```

and the output with my Stringbuilder to:

```
builder1.append((int)chararray1[i]);
```

But the "ß" is 223 instead of 225. Other characters are wrong too.